# Sorting different rows based on multiple conditions

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a contacts table having two columns priority and name. Consider I have some 500 entries. I need to sort by following conditions

- First order by priority and top 20 should be returned.
- After that remaining rows to be sorted based on name.

Can this be possible in a single query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine multiple queries with [UNION](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#compound).
Additional subqueries are needed to be able to user ORDER BY/LIMIT (otherwise, ORDER BY would apply to the entire result of the UNION).
The LIMIT 20 subquery must be repeated to exclude the top 20 rows from the second query:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT *
      FROM Contacts
      ORDER BY priority DESC
      LIMIT 20)
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT *
      FROM Contacts
      WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT ID
                       FROM Contacts
                       ORDER BY priority DESC
                       LIMIT 20)
      ORDER BY name)
```

Comment: @CL: out of curiosity, is sqlite guaranteed to give the same 20 ids in the first and second subquery if they are not uniquely specified by priority (e.g. if you have 50 Contacts entries tied with the highest priority)?

Comment: No. You would have to add another sorting column (ID or rowid) to break ties.